# AppSync batch call for nested properties

Tags: rest, graphql, aws-appsync

My backend REST API takes a list of `id`'s and returns a list of, say, `Person` objects whose `id` was requested. Each `Person` has a `children` property, which is a list of `Person.id`. A nice family tree.

```
// GET /id/[1,2]
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jacob",
  "children": [3, 4]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Jack",
  "children": [5, 6]
}
```

Using AppSync to front said API, I have a resolver for `children` that makes a call to my API using the following template:

```
#set( $myMap = {
  "id" : $context.source.children
} )

{
  "version" : "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Invoke",
  "payload": {
    "id": $util.toJson($myMap)
  }
}
```

This works fine, and AppSync nicely "unwraps" the `children` array with the appropriate `Person`. The issue is that if a `Person` has `N` children, then `N` calls are made to my backend API if the client requests the children.

Since my API could take all of the children IDs for all `N` children at once, it would be nice if AppSync had a way to batch those calls, and then somehow untangle the response and put each `Person` in the right place.

## Question

Is there a way to batch all of individual calls for a nested property into a single call per nested level?

#### Edit

My GraphQL schema for the example above:

```
type Person {
  id: Int
  name: String
  children: [Person]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AppSync supports this type of batching behavior when proxied through AWS Lambda. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html and search for "Batching".

With that being said, based on what you have provided, can you not just call your batch API from the `Person.children` field for example?

You specified that you have an object:

```
type Person {
  id: Int
  name: String
  childIds: [String]
  children: [Person]
}
```

Can you not just add the field `Person.children` that calls your batch HTTP endpoint with the list of children?

```
type Person {
  id: Int
  name: String
  childIds: [String]

  # An HTTP resolver that performs a GET to /id/[1,2]
  # where [1,2] comes from $ctx.source.childIds
  children: [Person]
}
```

This will perform a single batch call to your HTTP endpoint per person.

Answer (score 0):

AppSync supports this type of batching behavior to an extent when proxied through AWS Lambda. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html and search for "Batching".

With that being said, based on what you have provided, can you not just call your batch API from the `Person.children` field for example?

You specified that you have an object:

```
type Person {
  id: Int
  name: String
  childIds: [String]
  children: [Person]
}
```

Can you add the field `Person.children` that calls your batch HTTP endpoint with the list of children provided by the $ctx.source object?

```
type Person {
  id: Int
  name: String
  childIds: [String]

  # An HTTP resolver that performs a GET to /id/[1,2]
  # where [1,2] comes from $ctx.source.childIds
  children: [Person]
}
```

This will perform a single batch call to your HTTP endpoint per person.