# How to configure Appsync to retrieve data from a HTTP endpoint to populate a list?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-api-gateway, aws-appsync, vtl

I have two http endpoints setup:

```
GET /users/{userId}
GET /users/{userId}/notes/{noteId}
```

The GET User returns a payload which includes a list of multiple `noteId`s, which can be used to make multiple requests to the GET Note endpoint.

I am trying to configure Appsync to be able to fetch all of this data in a single query, but I can't get the list to populate with objects.

Schema:

```
type Query {
  getUser(userId: String!): User
  getNote(userId: String!, noteId: String!): Note
}

type User {
  userId: ID!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  notes: [Note]
}

type Note {
  noteId: ID!
  noteText: String!
  createdDatetime: Int!
}
```

I have a data source setup for each of the endpoints and I have a resolver for `getUser` and for `getNote` - I also have a resolver for `User.notes` which is the same as `getNote`. These resolvers have this response mapping:

```
#if($ctx.error)
  $util.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end
#if($ctx.result.statusCode == 200)
    $ctx.result.body
#else
    $utils.appendError($ctx.result.body, "$ctx.result.statusCode")
#end
```

My resolver for the GET Note (including `User.note` field resolver) endpoint looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "method": "GET",
    "resourcePath": $util.toJson("/prod/users/$ctx.args.userId/notes/$ctx.args.noteId"),
    "params":{
        "headers":{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    }
}
```

I can see from the logs, that Appsync attempts to run the GET Note resolver, but that the resource path doesn't seem to get populated with any ids? (I can see this in the custom Authorizer on the endpoint, which logs out the method ARN which still includes the `$ctx.args...`

It feels like this is a common use case, but I can't find a solution, or examples anywhere. Is my approach correct, or do I need a different solution?

Comment: May I know how are you calling `getNote` from `getUser`?

Comment: Hi @Myz, I missed that from my question - I've updated it now. I have a field resolver which points to the same mappings as the getNote resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first problem is with your `User.notes` resolver and how you are accessing `userId` and `noteId`. When you have field resolvers, you should use `ctx.source` to access the the parent field [[Ref.]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html). For example, you should use `ctx.source.userId` in your `User.notes` field resolver.

Secondly, as you are going to fetch individual notes from your `getNote` HTTP endpoint, AppSync supports this type of behavior when proxied through AWS Lambda using `BatchInvoke`. Please see "Advanced Use Case: Batching" on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html) link to get better idea. Also, I think this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504905/appsync-batch-call-for-nested-properties) is relevant to your use case.

One other possibility is to have another HTTP endpoint to get all the user's notes at once but I am not sure if this is possible in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Myz. I had not considered using Lambda Resolvers before, but I think that's the right way to go. A new HTTP endpoint seems to go against my reasoning for using graphql (separation of the microservices from the front end logic).